# Algorithm to determine size of a room from video feed

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, opencv, video-processing

Does anybody know of a image analysis algorithm with which I can determine how large(approximately, in real-life measurements, let's say width in meters or something) a room is out of one(or multiple) video recordings of this room?

I'm currently using OpenCV as my image library of choice, but I haven't gotten very far in terms of learning image analysis algorithms, just a name drop would be fine.

Thanks

Edit: Okay, a little bit of clarification I just got from the people involved. I basically have no control how the video feed is taken, and can't guarantee that there are multiple data sources. I however have a certain points location in the room and I'm supposed to place something in relation to that point. So I would probably looking at trying to identify the edges of the room, then identifying how far procentual the given location is in the room and then guess how large the room is.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done without a frame of reference. And just finding the edges of the room is a hard problem on its own.

Comment: This isn't a simple problem to solve at all.  Do you need to be able to do this completely autonomously?  You'll have significantly more luck if you can, e.g., have a user find features in the room and use image processing and camera calibration information to extrapolate.  If the camera is moving, maybe look into "structure from motion".  No matter what, unless there is something of known size available in the image, you will only ever know dimensions up to a scaling factor; i.e., 5x10, 10x20, 20x40, etc.

Comment: Do you have any control on how the image is collected?

Comment: Sadly I have no control over the source image and no user input available. See my edit.

Comment: Can you relate exactly the task you've been given? Often in problems like this you have to take shortcuts that really depend on the problem constraints. Because in the general case it's very tough.

Comment: Basically I have to draw/place an object into a room. I don't know the absolute location of the object, but I know the location of another point and I know how far the object is away from that other point. So far I have to give more of a proof-of-concept (my requirements are very vague) so I don't know in which way I'll get the locations...  I'll try to give are real-world example: I have a real-world video of a room and I know that a point in that room is ~4m away from one edge. Now I have to draw a line 2m left of that point, as accurately as possible

Answer (score 4):

Awfully difficult (yet interesting!) problem.

If you are thinking in doing this in a completely automated way I think you'll have a lots of issues. But I think this is doable if an operator can mark control points in a set of pictures.

Your problem can be stated more generally as finding the distance between two points in 3D space, when you only have the locations of these points in two or more 2D pictures taken from different points of view. The process will work more or less like this:

- The pictures will come with camera location and orientation information. For example, let's say that you get two pictures, with the same camera orientation and where the two pictures were taken with the camera three feet apart horizontally. You will have to define a reference origin for the 3D space in which the cameras are located, for example, you can say that the left picture has the camera at (0,0,0) and the right picture at (3,0,0), and both will be facing forward, which would be an orientation of (0,0,1). Or something like that.
- Now the operator comes and marks the two corners of the room in both pictures. So you have 2 sets of 2D coordinates for each corner.
- You must know the details of your camera and lens (field of view, lens distortion,   aberrations, etc.). The more you know about how your camera deforms the image the more accurate you can make your estimate. This is the same stuff panorama stitching software do to achieve a better stitch. See [PanoTools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/) for info on this.
- Here comes the fun part: you will now do the inverse of a [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) for each of your 2D points. The perspective projection takes a point in 3D space and a camera definition and computes a 2D point. This is used to represent tridimensional objects in a flat surface, like a computer screen. You are doing the reverse of that, for each 2D point you will try to obtain a 3D coordinate. Since there isn't enough information in a 2D point to determine depth, the best you can do from a single 2D point is obtain a line in 3D space that passes through the lens and through the point in question, but you don't know how far from the lens the point is. But you have the same 2D point in two images, so you can compute two 3D lines from different camera locations. These lines will not be parallel, so they will intersect at a single point. The intersection point of the 3D lines will be a good estimation of the location of the 3D point in space, and in the coordinates of your reference camera 3D space.
- The rest is easy. When you have the estimated 3D locations of the two points of interest, you just compute the [3D distance](http://web.horacemann.org/academics/math/pcbch/vect/3d.html) between them, and that's the number that you want.

Pretty easy, huh?

Comment: If you have the camera location and orientation, that means your camera operator was aware of the task and was carrying a measuring instrument. In those conditions, I would rather instruct him/her to measure the room instead :)

Comment: Sure, but note that the photographer does not need to know much, as long as he can take two pictures (or a video) with the camera facing forward and the distance traveled by the camera can be estimated. It's all estimations, the better the input numbers the more accurate your distance estimate will be.

Comment: Sadly, I can't assume that there will be at least two video sources.

Comment: If you have a video and the camera is moving then you can select two frames from the video that present different points of view of your room.

Comment: I also can't assume that the camera is moving, but I'm nevertheless fascinated by your solution

Comment: Thanks. A solution like the one I described above was used to track the 3D positions of soccer players and the ball, so that a 3D animation of a game can be constructed. The input was two videos shot from different locations in the stadium, and the lines in the soccer field were used for alignment purposes. Fun project!